# SQL WHERE string LIKE field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a table tracking links structured as follows:

```
id
domain_name
traffic_count
enabled
created_at
```

Let's say I have a record with domain_name of "some-domain.com", and then let's say I want to find the record having that domain, except all I have to go by is a subdomain of that domain.

I essentially want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM links 'subdomain.some-domain.com' LIKE %domain_name%"
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 11):

Updated (thanks to Chad Johnson):

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE 'subdomain.some-domain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain_name, '%')
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a where clause?

Comment: Very close! Looks like this works: SELECT * FROM links WHERE 'subdomain.some-domain.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', domain_name, '%')

Comment: @ChadJohnson, yes, that's why I asked which DB. On MySQL you have to use `CONCAT`. Also, you need a `WHERE`, like `SELECT * FROM links WHERE` (etc).

Comment: @ChadJohnson Note of caution, this query won't be able to use indexes or even worse (as SQL Server seems to do) builds a temporary index in memory, answers the question and throws the index away. In other words, don't use on a high traffic site without testing performance thoroughly.