# MS Access 2010: SQL WHERE string LIKE field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

A similar (not MS Access) question was posed and answered here. I have the same question within the context of an MS Access 2010 Application:

[SQL WHERE string LIKE field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523829/sql-where-string-like-field)

The following given solution is not applicable in MS Access as that application does not support CONCAT:

```
SELECT * FROM links 'subdomain.some-domain.com' LIKE %domain_name%"
```

My question - how in MS Access 2010 SQL may I specify "Include all records where String type field1 contains the substring given by String type field2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InStr` function might be a viable alternative here:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE InStr(1, 'subdomain.some-domain.com', domain_column) > 0
```

This solution has the potential drawback that it would return true if `domain_column` were a substring of any portion of the input, but then again so would your `LIKE` option.

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like`.  The code in MS Access looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE "subdomain.some-domain.com" LIKE "*" & domain_name & "*"
```

Of course, `instr()` is also very reasonable, unless your column contains other wildcards.

Comment: Upvoted.  And now there is the question as to whether `LIKE` or `INSTR` would perform better in this case.